# Which dns record is actually responsible for taking the user to the desired url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, vhosts

**What I am trying to achieve**

on a digitalocean droplet, I want to host two apps on different subdomains .

i.e. *eds.extragrip.in*, and *www.extragrip.in*

I also have a domain `extragrip.in` bought from google domains.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED** : ..
so for this, following tutorials [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-point-to-digitalocean-nameservers-from-common-domain-registrars) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts),

I wrote this .conf file and copied it in `etc\apace2\sites-available` and enabled it with `a2ensite`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/eds/
         ServerName eds.extragrip.in

        <Directory /var/www/eds/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**view of my domain settings (see the image at the end) **

Now my user can successfully access both the sites. But which action is actually responsible for actually taking the user to `www.extragrip.in` and `eds.extragrip.in` ?  `Registered Hosts` record on the domains page (see image below)? the `A` custom resource record? or the Virtual Hosts configuration?

**In other words, Which of the above settings are optional and not mandatory?**

[image]

Comment: All 3 are necessary.

Comment: then what does the www CNAME  record do ( see at the end)